# Entity Framework is not creating database or tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

- Tried to first create the database using Microsoft SQL Server Managment Server. I was not able to use my current credentials as creating a new database resulted in an error. This was solved by using my admin credentials.
- Started the application as a blank project but am using web forms.
- There was not anything in application start that would suggest Entity would create a database.
- Verified that SQL Express was running.

  - In VS I am able to connect to the server and view my databases in SQL Server Object Explorer, however viewing Server Explorer will show my connection name and the database will have a red x.
  - In VS under server explorer, I can type in .\SQLEXPRESS under server name and see the system databases but I cannot see my cfsEnergy DB  under Connect to a database > Select or enter a database name.
- Using Visual Studio 2015
- Tried to add my username and admin account to the what I believe is the SQL Express group using the following script: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wadewegner/1677788/raw/16862d429feaa5d2d799533c548632365a2f04ff/addselftosqlsysadmin.cmd

/App_code/departments.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace cfsEnergyManagement.App_Code
{
    public class department
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public List<utilityUse> utilityUse { get; set;  }
    }
}
```

/App_code/utilityUse.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace cfsEnergyManagement.App_Code
{
    public class utilityUse
    {
        public string utilityID { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string year { get; set; }
        public string month { get; set; }
        public int kiloWattHour { get; set; }
        public int tonHour { get; set;  }
        public int kiloPoundsHour { get; set; }
        public int netCost { get; set; }
    }
}
```

/App_Code/dbContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace cfsEnergyManagement.App_Code
{
    public class cfsEnergyDb: DbContext
    {
    public DbSet<department> departments { get; set; }
      public DbSet<utilityUse> utilityUses { get; set; }

    }
}
```

dbContextRun.cs

```
namespace cfsEnergyManagement.App_Code
{
    public class dbContextRun
    {

        cfsEnergyDb CfsEnergyDb = new cfsEnergyDb();

    }
}
```

Connection String: web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="cfsEnergyDb" connectionString="server=SQLEXPRESS;integrated security=SSPI;database=cfsEnergy" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Do you have any code that actually instantiates your context? If it is never instantiated, I don't think it will do much...

Comment: I have another class called dbContextRun.cs but does nothing:  public class dbContextRun    {
   
        cfsEnergyDb CfsEnergyDb = new cfsEnergyDb();
        
    }

Comment: And I'm assuming you are actually _executing_ that code somehow? Is there a Main(), or any other entry point in your application? Or are you making a library, which cannot and will not actually run by itself?

Comment: If you want to create your database without adding any data use DbContext.Database.Initialize(bool).

Comment: "The name 'dbContext.Database.Initialize' does not exist in the current context. Does not work in the same file as dbset. I tried to add this into Global.asax.cs > Application Start and IntelliSense does not show a "Database".  Using the word Database also returns and error.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not instantiating **cfsEnergyDb** class. Entity framework only and only create database when you will try to access any data for the first time from database table(any db queries). So try to access data from table and EF will create all the tables for you in database(specified in connection string).

Comment: I added another file with cfsEnergyDb CfsEnergyDb = new cfsEnergyDb();Is there something else that needs to be added in order for Entity to work properly?

Comment: If still not created then try to access data like cfsEnergyDb.departments.ToList(); after instantiating  check it will create surely

Comment: Says cfsEnergyDb.department.ToList does not exist in the current context.

Comment: var deptlist = cfsEnery. type this thing and intellisense will populate all db set and check what you are getting and after that apppend toList(), Check that

Comment: When I try to delete the database I added manually using admin from the SQL Server Object Explorer using Visual studio on a normal account I get "The Execute permission was denied on the subject 'sp_delete_database_backuphistory', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. Is this because I don't have access rights?

Comment: may be. but if you dont have access for creating new db then it will thow exception. check it.

Comment: Ok I gave my sqlexpress the right permissions but now I get errors that say type department in \App_Code\departments.cs conflicts with the imported type 'department' in 'cfsEnergyManagement, Version=1.0.0.0,...." in dbContext.cs

Comment: do you have teamviewer can you show what you are doing

Comment: Alright so it looks like ti created a database file in users/username/cfsEnergyDb.mdf and I changed my server in the connection string to  <add name="cfsEnergyDb" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=cfsEnergyDb;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> However I don't see the db or tables in SQL server Object Explorer

Comment: "The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe."